# In Kotlin two exact suspend fun tests run correctly in same file, but incorrectly when placed in different files

Tags: kotlin, testing, cassandra, suspend

Basically I had 17 tests in same file that run correctly every time. When I tried to move some to different files, they conflict. I boiled it down to running same test twice. Same file works fine every time, but in different .kt files one of tests won't pass - won't read data from database that should be there. Tests upsert data to Cassanrda database. I suspect its because they are running in parallel. I tried to use runBlocking - it doesn't help.

Edit: I've made a workaround: upserting unique id in every test so they won't conflict, so it works for now. But it won't work for test, for example, counting number of upserted fields, because this would be affected by another test still. If you have better solution, it would be interesting to hear

Comment: It would best if you made the tests insensitive to the fact that other tests are running concurrently. You can probably play with the concurrency of your tests using facilities from whatever testing framework you're using, but most likely it will just be simpler to have tests that are ok to run in parallel.

Comment: What test runner do you use?

Comment: Why not spin up a separate Cassandra cluster for each tests file?